# Two switches and one bulb

Tags: switches

I have a battery, 2 sw's and one bulb.
The question asks to design a circuit that with every change in one of the sw's the bulb will change it state - no matter what is the other switch state.
How can I dot that?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please quickly realise that this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Ask a clear question, showing your work and findings so far in considerable detail. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: Homework. What have you tried?

Comment: That title reminds me of something...

Comment: Homework questions with no attempt at a solution are closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the circuit for the landing light switch, one switchback bottom of stairs and second at the top of the stairs.

http://www.lightwiring.co.uk/two-way-switching-3-wire-system-new-harmonised-cable-colours/

Comment: Please don't do homework for people who show no effort.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Yes you can use the corresponding switching from house installation.
If your switches have only two pins you have to use a kip relay

Comment: Hej, Jorn. Please don't do homework for people who show no effort. Tak.

Comment: Jorn - Welcome to the site :-) However, you have broken 2 site rules. (a) You added a signature to both of your answers (one was converted to a comment). Please [don't add a signature](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). I have removed it for you, this time. (b) When you include information (e.g. images, quotes etc.) sourced from elsewhere, you need to [correctly reference it](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).  (c) I recommend you read the [site help](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help) and [tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour).